# jquery - show / hide elements rows by elemenst in data-id array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have table with rows like that:

```
<tr class="listRow" data-id="[11,0]">...</tr>
<tr class="listRow" data-id="[1,2,3]">...</tr>
```

How i can using JQuery filter specific rows with element in array? For example by button click show all rows with 1 in array and hide rest.

Edit - my sample code so far:

i don't know how to filtering elements in data-id array.

```
$(document).on('click','#filterList',function()
    {
        var element = $(this).data("id");

// how to filter elements in rows

    }
);
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried. SO isn't a free code writing service. The objective here is for you to post your attempts to solve your own issue and others help when they don't work as expected. See [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: And what is initial state? All rows shown, or?

Comment: initial all rows are shown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand correctly:

```
$('#check').click(function() {

$('.listRow').each(function() {
if($.inArray(1, $(this).data().id)>-1) {
$(this).show();
}
else {
$(this).hide()
}


});
});
```

```js
$('#check').click(function() {

$('.listRow').each(function() {
if($.inArray(1, $(this).data().id)>-1) {
$(this).show();
}
else {
$(this).hide()
}


});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="tg">
<thead>
  <tr class="listRow" data-id="[1,0]">
    <th class="tg-0pky">Here is 1</th>
    <th class="tg-0pky">xxxx</th>
    <th class="tg-0pky"></th>
    <th class="tg-0pky"></th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr class="listRow" data-id="[11,0]">
    <td class="tg-0pky">Not 1</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
    <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
    <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="listRow" data-id="[15,0]" >
    <td class="tg-0pky">Not 1</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
    <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
    <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="listRow"  data-id="[1,0,3]">
    <td class="tg-0pky" >Here is 1</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
    <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
    <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<button id="check">
Click
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

- when you press the button, loop through all the elements that have a `data-id`
- parse the data-id as json, which will give you an array
- if the array includes the id you're looking for, set the class to `hide` or `show` (where they have the display css assigned accordingly)

here's what that might look like without jquery and using style and opacity. Usually it's done using class but this is for demonstration purposes, changing to use classes should be straight forward.

```js
function findElsById(id){
  var matches = []
  document.querySelectorAll('[data-id]').forEach(function(el){
    try{
      var arr = JSON.parse(el.dataset.id)
      if (arr.includes(id)) matches.push(el)
    } catch (e){
      // prolly not valid json
    }
  })
  return matches
}

function show(id){
  var els = findElsById(id);
  console.log('show', id, '\nshowing: ', els)
  if (els) {
    els.forEach(function(el){
      el.style = 'opacity:1'
    })
  }
}

function hide(id){
  var els = findElsById(id);
  console.log('hide', id, '\nhiding: ', els)
  if (els) {
    els.forEach(function(el){
      el.style = 'opacity:0.1'
    })
  }
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr class="listRow" data-id="[1,0]"><td>1, 0</td></tr>
<tr class="listRow" data-id="[1,2]"><td>1, 2</td></tr>
</table>
<button onclick="hide(0)">-0</button>
<button onclick="hide(1)">-1</button>
<button onclick="hide(2)">-2</button>
<button onclick="show(0)">+0</button>
<button onclick="show(1)">+1</button>
<button onclick="show(2)">+2</button>
```